# Stop record thread witn commit results in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, multithreading

There is a Put method: 
`@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/fias/{fileName}", method = PUT)`. This method parses files. Parsing occurs in a separate thread. Therefore, for the user, the method works instantly and returns the ID of the created entity in the Mongo database.

There is a Post method: 
`@RequestMapping (value = "/ api / v1 / fias / interrupt / {objectId}", method = POST)`. This method should suspend the thread that parses the file from the POST method. **Can this be implemented?**

I try like this:

```
@Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executorService() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("codeinside-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/fias/{fileName}", method = PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Document> update(@PathVariable(value="fileName") String fileName) throws BadParamException, NotFinishProcessException {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(fiasQueryService.updateFiasByFileName(fileName));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/fias/interrupt/{objectId}", method = POST)
public ResponseEntity<Document> interrupt(@PathVariable(value="objectId") String objectId) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(fiasQueryService.interrupt(objectId));
}

@Service
public class FiasQueryServiceImpl implements FiasQueryService {
    @Autowired
    private AsyncFias asyncFias;
    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executorService;

    private CompletableFuture<Integer> asyncResult;

    @Override
    public Document updateFiasByFileName(String fileName) throws NotFinishProcessException {
        String settingsPath = settingsService.getStringParam(FIAS_FILE_PATH);
        File file = new File(settingsPath + "/" + fileName);

        ObjectId objectId = checkAndInsertStatus(file.getName().toLowerCase());
        asyncResult = asyncFias.startUpdate(file, objectId);
        return new Document("_id", objectId.toString()).append("success", true);
    }

    @Override
    public Document interrupt(String objectIdString) {
        setStatus(new ObjectId(objectIdString), INTERRUPT);
        asyncResult.cancel(true);
        Integer cnt = null;
        if (asyncResult.isCancelled()) {
            ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(objectIdString);
            try {
                cnt = asyncResult.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            setStatus(objectId, INTERRUPT);
            return new Document("success", true).append("count", cnt);
        } else {
            return new Document("success", false);
        }
    }
}

@Service
public class AsyncFias {
    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public CompletableFuture<Integer> startUpdate(File file, ObjectId objectId) {
        // a lot of code.......
        ClientSession session = mongo.startSession(ClientSessionOptions.builder().causallyConsistent(true).build());
        MongoDatabase db = getDb(collectionInfo);
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = 
        db.getCollection(collectionInfo.getCollectionName());
        collection.insertMany(session, dbObjects);
        session.close();
        // a lot of code.......
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(count);
    }
}
```

But I get NPE in the line `asyncResult.cancel (true);`
I also tried to stop the workflow in this way: `executorService.shutdown ();`
But in this case, the records that should have been recorded by the time the stream stopped were rolled back. How can I stop the recording stream so that the currently recorded recordings are saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the startUpdate method:

```
@Service
public class AsyncFias {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncFias.class);

    private final FiasFileService fiasFileService;
    private final MongoDBService mongoDBService;

    private AtomicBoolean inProgress = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    AsyncFias(FiasFileService fiasFileService, MongoDBService mongoDBService) {
        this.fiasFileService = fiasFileService;
        this.mongoDBService = mongoDBService;
    }

    public Integer getIncrement(){
        return count.get();
    }

    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Future<Void> startUpdate(File file) throws InterruptedException {
        DbfUtilEnum utilEnum = DbfUtilEnum.fromFileName(file.getName().toLowerCase());
        DbfMapper<Document> objMapper = utilEnum.getDbfMapper();
        List<Document> dbObjects = fiasFileService.processFile(file, objMapper);
        String collectionName = utilEnum.getCollectionName();
        EntryMetaInfo metaInfo = new EntryMetaInfo(collectionName, collectionName, null, false, null);
        List<List<Document>> lists = ListUtils.partition(dbObjects, 1000);
        if (inProgress.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            for (List<Document> it : lists) {
                //Thread.sleep(2000);
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("Cancelled");
                    inProgress.set(false);
                    break;
                }
                mongoDBService.insertBulk(metaInfo, it);
                count.getAndIncrement();
                try {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    AsyncResult<Void> result = new AsyncResult<>(null);
                    result.cancel(true);
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        lists.clear();
        count.set(0);
        AsyncResult<Void> result = new AsyncResult<>(null);
        result.cancel(true);
        return result;
    }
}

@Service
public class FiasQueryServiceImpl implements FiasQueryService {
    private Future<Void> asyncResult;
    // a lot of code
    @Override
    public Document updateFiasByFileName(String fileName) throws NotFinishProcessException, InterruptedException {
        String settingsPath = settingsService.getStringParam(FIAS_FILE_PATH);
        File file = new File(settingsPath + "/" + fileName);
        ObjectId objectId = checkAndInsertStatus(file.getName().toLowerCase());
        asyncResult = asyncFias.process(file);
        return new Document("_id", objectId.toString()).append("success", true);
    }
    @Override
    public Document interrupt(String objectIdString) {
        asyncResult.cancel(true);

        if (asyncResult.isCancelled()) {
            log.info("asyncResult.isCancelled()");
            ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(objectIdString);
            setStatus(objectId, INTERRUPT);
            return new Document("success", true).append("count", asyncFias.getIncrement());
        } else {
            return new Document("success", false);
        }
    }
}
```

General conclusion: for objects of the Future type, the cancel (true) method must be called 2 times: at the time of creation of Future and at the moment of stopping the working thread.